# issue with addChild's X and Y value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have an Enemy class that deals with my monster moving and attacking. Within that class, I have another class called enemyMagic, which is a blank movieclip that serves as a masterclass to different movieclips that I will make.

So in the enemyMagic class, I add a movieclip called attack1

```
public var attack1:Attack1 = new Attack1;    
       public function EnemyMagic() {
                ////////////CREATE THE TIMER//////////
                masterEnemyAttackTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, mastertimer);

                ////////////ATTACKS/////////
                //TIER 1//
                addChild(attack1);

            }
```

And in the enemy class, I add the enemyMagic when the enemy is attacking a certain position.

```
for (var k:int = 0; k < Main.tileset.length; k++)
            {

                if (! Main.tileset[k].tileMiddle.hitTestObject(this.enemyVisionPoint))
                {
                    if (Main.tileset[k].tileHP !== 0)
                    {
                        attackoptions.push(Main.tileset[k]);
                    }
                    if (Main.tileset[k].tileMiddle.hitTestObject(Main.player.visionPoint))
                    {
                        addChild(enemymagic);
                        Main.tileset[k].outline.gotoAndStop("attack");
                        this.enemymagic.x = (Main.tileset[k].x);
                        this.enemymagic.y = (Main.tileset[k].y);
                        trace(enemymagic.x, enemymagic.y, Main.tileset[k].x, Main.tileset[k].y);
```

For some reason, the enemymagic is tracing the exact same number as the tile's x and y, but it isn't adding it on the tile. It adds it way off the screen. I think it might be because it starts on the enemy's x and y and then calculates?

So my question is how can I get the enemymagic movie clip to get exactly on the position of the tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things. First, when you do a plain `addChild()` the base coordinate system of the child is the one of its parent, which is your `Enemy` instance, which is of course at somewhere nonzero. And then you assign it the coordinates of `Main.tileset[k]` which has a different parent (most likely instance of `Main`). This creates the distance you speak of. So, in order to locate your magic over the exact tile, either use `this.globalToLocal(Main.tileset[k].localToGlobal(PZERO))` where `PZERO` is a `new Point()` constant (or write `new Point()` instead of `PZERO`, but this will create another empty `Point` object and will quickly escalate), or do an `addChild()` directly to the tile you are attacking with unaltered coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, I would have to create a new point. Is there a specific x and y value I should put? Also, I get an implicit coercion error, which I guess means that the x value of the magic isn't playing nice with the PZERO. I did consider adding the child to the Tile class itself, but I thought it was ideal to have everything related to the enemy on the enemy. Thanks man!

Comment: `public static const PZERO:Point=new Point();` That's how you declare a zero point. The trick is, your tile's zero point (equals anchor point at design time) is usually either upper left or dead center of the tile. If the former, then declare `PCENTER` equalling the center of tile. And about adding to enemy - imagine you throwing a magic, then rotating the enemy 90 degrees leftwards. Bam, your magic is no longer at selected tile. As soon as anything detaches from the enemy (bullets, magics, broken parts etc), it's better to NOT `addChild()` them to the enemy, but add to a class that holds all.

Comment: Ok. I do have the enemy move every 10 seconds, so the magic would be affected. My best bet would be adding it on the tile, or even the Main class?